# Initiate a string variable to empty

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

Is possible in SharePoint 2013 workflow to initiate a string variable to empty or null?

```
Ex:
Set Variable: v_temp_related to <Empty or null>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a workflow variable containing a single space character and use the `Trim` function to blank the variable.

http://officepowerups.com/2014/01/28/how-to-blank-a-text-field-with-a-workflow/

Comment: The link is broken. But Ok, I get it.

Comment: in office 365 if you set variable to (space). When you publish the workflow it will thrown an error. To overcome this problem I set variable to some character then use the replace and trim action.